# Importing Time Series In r

Tags: r, time-series, analysis

[my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0567.jpg) I am trying to implement Time Series Analysis on a data set which has two attributes (Year & Sales). Year are 2016,2017 & 2018 for which there are average sales value for all 12 months. My data looks like below:

```
          JAN     FEB     MAR     APR       MAY      JUNE       
  2016    4457.   4,105   4,276   4712.   5,116      4,512     
  2017    4,222   5,432   4,816   5,018   4,497      4,603      
  2018    4,355   4,972   4,868   4,665   4,735      4,926
```

This is just some part of my data set to get an idea how it looks like. The months are JAN to DEC. Now I want to know, firstly, how to import this data set into R? As I obviously cannot import it like this because it treats all the columns like X1,X2 etc and these becomes too many variables. Secondly, R takes this data set as "data.frame". How can I convert it into just "ts". I have tried

```
data.ts<- as.ts(myData)
```

but it converts it into

> "mts" "ts" "matrix"

and moreover, it shows my frequency 1 while it should 
be 12. Please help me. I am stuck at the starting.

Comment: `as.ts(myData, from=c(2016,1), frequency=12)` should help you.

Comment: This command converts it into "mts" "ts" "matrix" . I want it to be "ts" only. And when I run frequency(myData) It shows frequency 1 when I have set it to be 12. Please help.

Comment: I have included the data set in my question. Can you please tell how should I import it in R ?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to restructure your data to be in long format which can be done with the gather function from tidyr.

```
library(tidyr)
myData <- myData %>% tidyr::gather(timeperiod, sales, JAN:DEC)
```

Then your data will be structured to create a time series:

```
ts <- as.ts(data, from=c(2016,1), frequency=12)
```

Comment: Great! Let me know if that helps. If it does, you can select this as an answer